# How to Design Schema for Many To Many for a single Table

Tags: schema, information-schema

What is the right way to design schema for self Nested or many to many relationship for single Table

Table:Products

- id
- name
- status

Need to Match/save Products with related Products.

ex: Related products for
product 1 is 3,4

product 2 is 5,6

product 3 is 1

product 4 is 1

product 5 is 2

product 6 is 2

Comment: What operations should be performed with this relational data? Only store/retrieve? or search/update/etc.?

Comment: only store & retrieve

Comment: If so then you may store this data in this table in additional TEXT/JSON column in serialized format (CSV, JSON).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would create a second table called `RelatedProducts` like so (pseudo-code since you didn't mention a specific database system):

```
CREATE TABLE RelatedProducts
(
    ProductId INT,
    RelatedProductId INT,
    CONSTRAINT FK_RelatedProducts_Related_To_Products FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES Products (ProductId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_RelatedProducts_Is_Product FOREIGN KEY (RelatedProductId) REFERENCES Products (ProductId),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Related_Products PRIMARY KEY (ProductId, RelatedProductId)
);
```

And then store 1 row per `Product` and a `RelatedProduct`. Then you can use this bridge table to self-join the `Products` table to get any other meta-data for `RelatedProducts`, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    Products.Id,
    Products.Name,
    RelatedProductDetails.Id,
    RelatedProductDetails.Name,
    RelatedProductDetails.Status
FROM Products
INNER JOIN RelatedProducts
    ON Products.Id = RelatedProducts.ProductId
INNER JOIN Products AS RelatedProductDetails
    ON RelatedProducts.RelatedProductId = RelatedProductDetails.Id
WHERE Products.Id = 12345
```